# How do I attach scala sources to my maven jar?

Tags: scala, maven

I have a project with mixed java and scala code, that uses maven for dependency and build management. I use the `maven-source-plugin` to build a sources-jar that gets uploaded to my maven mirror, which works well for the *java* sources (in `src/main/java`), but not for the *scala* sources (in `src/main/scala`).

I didn't find any help on the `scala-maven-plugin` [webpage](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), but I may have missed out on something. Is it not possible to attach scala sources in the jar?

I should note that the class files are all there, so depending on the library works fine, it's just that the scala sources are missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem; I'd added the `maven-source-plugin` fine, but was seeing

```
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-sources) @ foo-bar ---
[INFO] No sources in project. Archive not created.
```

when I compiled my Scala project.

To fix this, I added the `add-source` goal to my `scala-maven-plugin` config, eg:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        ...
    </executions>
    ...
</plugin>
```

This adds your Scala source to the pom, which in turn allows the `maven-source-plugin` to find the source files and put them in a source jar.

See also http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html

Comment: This was the perfect solution! Thanks a ton! (sorry for the late reply, I didn't have time to test this until now)

Comment: I found that I needed to remove the `<goal>compile</goal>` (I was compiling in another execution anyway) and I didn't need the `<phase>process-resources</phase>`. And it's worth re-emphasizing that the `maven-source-plugin` still needs to be there.