# No source code jars is generated

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a maven project and I have add maven-source-plugin in the parent project pom file, but one of sub modules still don't generate source code jar, what might be wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Did you run `mvn source:jar` ?

Comment: yes, I run that, some of modules generate source code jar but some doesn't generate source code jars, this is very weird.

Comment: You need to look at what is different about the modules that it works for and the modules that it doesn't work for.  I don't think we can *guess* what the problem is.

Comment: I see message "No sources in project. Archive not created", but I do have source code under this module, why would it complain that ?

Comment: Again ... look at the project, the POM file, etc to see what is different.

Comment: It is resolved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716029/how-do-i-attach-scala-sources-to-my-maven-jar

Comment: Ah ... so this is a problem with a mixed Java / Scala project.  Its a pity you didn't mention  that.  (I've added the "scala" tag for the sake of future readers.)